# Making icon marker size variable depend on data value using CartoDB

Tags: symbology, carto

Is there any way in CartoDB where I can make the size of individual icon markers, visualized on a CartoDB map, variable and set according to its data value in a given data range?

Similar to the CartoDB "Bubble" visualization but i would like to be doing this for other Icon markers other than circle markers.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple using a bit of CartoCSS. First, set your map to a normal marker type. Where you select the color of the marker in the wizard, there is also an option for adding the image. Once you have added the image you want, go to the CartoCSS editor, and change the

```
marker-width: 12;
```

to

```
marker-width: [you_column_name];
```

and you should be all set. Just be sure that your column is numeric.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on chrome and firefox.  I see this error: "Error: marker-width property should be set"  Has anyone seen this work?  I changed "marker-width: 20" to marker-width: [attendees];  and attendees is a number field